# how to get integer values in a string with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var text = "rating-1-gray-3-blue";
```

i want to get value `13`

how can i do this . basically i want to get all integers inside a string .

i tried with `parseInt` , but it returns int when the integer value is at the beginning of the string

thanks in advance

Comment: All integers in a string would result in [1, 3] for your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var result = +text.replace(/\D/g, "");  // 13
```

Comment: .. and *reversed*: `var result = +text.match(/\d/g).join('');`

Comment: @jAndy if only creating a new array makes any sense :)

Comment: it does. It's even slightly faster for me (*Chrome*). http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-regexp-vs-regexp

Comment: @jAndy Any ideas why? `replace` does extra internal string iteration(s), while `match` not?

Comment: I honestly don't know the reason. Might even be because the different regexp matches `\D` vs. `\d`.

Comment: @jAndy I guess the match comes from ASCII ranges, where `c > 47 && c < 58` is the same as `c > 64 && c < 123` from performance POV. Besides, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result=text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

This removes all non 0-9 values from your string